# Which collation choose for SQL Server instance and database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on a Windows application based on a database SQL Server 2008 R2.
This application is currently sold to companies in Belgium, who use four languages: English, French, Dutch, German. And soon, the application will be sold to other countries in Europe and later in America.

Here are the questions I ask myself:

- For SQL server instance (one by country):

  - Which language to choose ?
  - Should we make the same choices on case sensitivity, and other accents for the database?
  - Must have a binary collation?
  - Impacts on temporary treatments (tempdb) ?
- For the database

  - Which language to choose ?
  - Should take into account the locale used with Windows client application?
- For development environments and recipe

  - How to develop and test the application by managing all countries ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: My little tidbit.  When you may be deploying on unknown-sql server....I always develop with a Case Sensitive collation.  Why?  I learned the hard way.  Back in 7.0 days, my company tried to deploy our database on the company's sql server, and they wanted case sensitive.  It cRapPed oUt aLl ovEr tHe PLaCe.  Several of us spent the next 4 days (Th,F,Sa,Su) fixing our many many stored procedures for CaSe sEnsiTivity.  Not sure why they were so gung-ho about case sensitivity. Years later, when I write the create scripts for a db and set the collation to case-sensitive, some jr devs still wig out.

Comment: +1 @granadaCoder: always develop on CS. Many a comercial tool fails this simple test of shame and error out on a CS server because their devs worked on a CI server...

Comment: This issue has been asked about [numerous times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+choose+collation) already on SO. Unfortunately the short answer is "it depends", so the best thing you can do is research the options and do some quick testing to see what fits well with your application design. My two cents would be to work only with Unicode data (i.e. `nchar` and `nvarchar`) and use a CI_AI collation because accents and case are often important. But since you can control this at the column level and in queries it's always possible to have exceptions for specific data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When working with a foreign language, or multiple languages, in SQL, I would recommend setting up the collation as CI_AI_SI to prevent any special character issues associated in character/string fields (i.e. concatenation, casts, etc). As a result, the language should also be Unicode. Taking into consideration all of the various scenarios you could run into, this is a catch-all scenario.

I might also suggest programming in nvarchar instead of your standard varchar. Yes, the data size is doubled, but it should help to alleviate an odd conversions you may have in your stored procedures.

Comment: The problem with this advice is that "special characters" (whatever that means) and case are very important. If I search for the Spanish word "mas" I don't want to get hits for "más" as well, because that means something different.

Comment: Very true. I didn't take that one into consideration. I'm glad we agree based on your comment above. Thank you for the catch!